# Extending Asp.net Identity entities AspNetUserRole and AspNetRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I would like to extend the latest version of ASP.net Core Identity entities AspNetUserRoles and AspNetRoles, but are unable to figure out if it’s possible and how to do it. I have looked “everywhere” on the internet, found many more or less identical questions, but almost everyone without any answer or if an answer the say use claims instead of roles. I intent to use clams indirectly through AspNetRoleClaims, but it’s easier to administrate claims for a user through AspNetRoles and therefor my need arises.

What I’d like to do is this:

With the AspNetUserRoles I’d also like to add a string field so that a user can have different roles in different parts of the application. Without using it for actual multitenancy, multitenancy is the best analog I can come out with. Different role in different department of a company could also be used as an analog.

With the AspNetRoles I’d like to add a string field for grouping/category purposes so that relates roles for e.g. a module can be made.

AspNetUserRole is the critical one, AspNetRoles is nice to have a workaround with the naming of roles could get me some part of the way with that one.

I’m using Asp.net Core, Code First, Entity Framework and Migrations, how do I make the extensions described above?

Comment: there is a nice guide here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/configuring-asp-net-identity

Comment: @ JohnB:
Nice Guide for getting into Identity, but sadly it covers no element of what I’m seeking an answer to.
Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Morny did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Comment: @Jazb That guide is of little help when using Asp.Net Core 3.1. How to extend the roles in 3.1?